# How to model a list where removing an item leaves existing iterators in a valid state?

Tags: list, data-structures, rust

I am implementing a solution to the [LeetCode LRU Cache problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/lru-cache/).
In C++, I would have a list of (key, value) tuples and an `unordered_map` from the key to the list iterator. The crucial property of `std::list` here is that when you remove a list element at a given list iterator, all other iterators remain valid.

How to implement this in Rust? Rust iterators are very unlike C++ iterators - more like the proposed ranges in C++, perhaps?

Comment: A forward-link-only list could be implemented as a `struct List<T> { head: T, tail: Option<Box<List<T>>> }`. There are several ways to do it. See also [*Learning Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists*](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/).

Comment: I don't think that given an iterator you can delete an element from a forward list.

Comment: @rincewind: Actually you can. The trick is to make the iterator contain a pointer to the node _before_ the data it refers to. It makes the code a bit more complex, but you can delete using it.

Comment: The Rust implementation of some data structures is much more convenient, and sometimes more efficient, if you use some `unsafe` code, and there is nothing wrong with that. I believe implementing an LRU cache where both lookup and insertion are O(1) is such a case. I suggest looking into the implementation of the [`lru-cache`](https://github.com/contain-rs/lru-cache) crate, which is based on [`linked-hash-map`](https://github.com/contain-rs/linked-hash-map),

Comment: Curious why the question is downvoted?